# Seam tracking with image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write a program that can detect the path which I draw on paper and give me the coordinates. I want to guide a welding torch with use of these coordinates.

With use of `edge()` I could detect the edges of the path, but I have trouble detecting the middle of the path. I tried to interpolate the edges coordinates with a `for` loop but I can't.

This is my code:

```
%% defining & Addressing an Image
img0=imread('C:\Users\Sohrab\Downloads\Project\photo_2018-11-02_22-07-15.jpg');
img0=rgb2gray(img0);
img1=imresize(img0,0.6);
img1=medfilt2(img1,[10,10]);

%% Applying Edge Detection
img2=edge(img1,'sobel');
img3=edge(img1,'canny');
imgI=img3;
[Row,Col]=size(imgI);


%% Interpolation
for i = 1:1:Row
    k=0;
    ONPixel=0;
    for j = 1:1:Col
        if(imgI(i,j)==1)
            ONPixel=ONPixel+j; 
            k=k+1;
        end
    end
            imgI(i,:)=0;
            if(k >= 2)
        imgI(i,floor(ONPixel/k))=1;
            end
end

%% showing Results
 figure;

 subplot(2,2,1)
 imshow(img1)
 title('ORGINAL IMAGE')

 subplot(2,2,2)
 imshow(img2)
 title('SOBEl METHOD')

 subplot(2,2,3)
 imshow(img3)
 title('CANNY Method')

 subplot(2,2,4)
 imshow(imgI)
 title('Interpolation')
```

**This is the result of interpolation:**
[image: (And this is the result.)]

the result is incorrect.

**This is the image I used for calculation:**

[image: (i did my calculation on image that i attached.)]

Comment: Ah, the problem is that your 'middle part', as you call it, it not fully black, but rather has white patches in between. This will result in most edge detector algorithms finding edges within the line. You can try to get the convex hull ([`convhull`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html)) of the whole thing and get it's edges and/or central axis.

Comment: The edge detection working well (or I taught it working well) but i don't want edges coordinate i need coordinate of a line between the edges.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said, and what I commented already on, read my last comment. Try `convhull()`

Comment: threshold it using graythresh, and then find first and last point in every row. Then find middle of these two points.

Comment: You can threshold using local thresholding(eg. sauvola thresholding) and then apply erosion followed by dilation with appropriate kernal, this morphological operation will remove the noisy edges because of white patches in between the the strip. After this find the edges and their horizontal mid points to draw the line.

Comment: does it work for the bottom part?(i mean the hook shape part)